# Can I install Nessus on two different systems with the same email address?

Tags: nessus

I have installed Nessus on one system and used the activation code that was emailed to me to register it, but I totally forgot the administrator password. I've already tried to use a forgotten username and password from the Nessus website, but they didn't send any mail reset. Right now I want to install another system and I like to use the same email address. Will I get a code?

I am using [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware).

Comment: They will not issue two codes for the same email address.  Try reusing the code you had previously; if you don't have that activation code, then you will have to use a different email address to request a new code.  This is, however, ***offtopic on Ask Ubuntu, as it is not an Ubuntu issue or question***.

Comment: But they already give me second code with same email address..

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the nessus admin's password through by following command:

On Windows:

```
C:\Program Files\Tenable\Nessus\nessus-chpasswd.exe <username>
```

Or on Linux:

```
/opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-chpasswd <username>
```

Comment: Well i tried to register again with same email address and they send me new code. Its ok to use the new code on new machine ?